# Missing libbcm_host.so when running chromium-browser

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

I'm trying to run `chromium-browser` on my raspberry pi (stretch 4.9.67-v7+) but I keep getting the error:

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser: error while loading shared 
libraries: libbcm_host.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file 
or directory
```

It worked before but stopped working when I uninstalled some other package. I've tried reinstalling the package several times and I also tried adding the `libbcm_host.so` in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` manually from https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/opt/vc/lib and then running `sudo ldconfig -v`. It pops up in the trace as

```
libbcm_host.so -> libbcm_host.so
```

under both `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` but running `chromium-browser` still gives me the same error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the `/opt/vc` folder had gone missing. The issue was resolved by installing the libraries again with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libraspberrypi0 libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi-bin
```